# How to merge a GeoJSON and an OSM file into a single OSM file? I want to merge Microsoft buildings dataset into a single OSM file

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, geojson

I'm using a video game tool that can take OSM data and import it to Unity automatically. The issue is that OSM doesn't have a lot of buildings, so my game doesn't, either. I found the Microsoft Building dataset, which is AWESOME.

I downloaded an OSM file of Indiana. I also downloaded the GeoJSON file of the Microsoft Building Dataset. It's been hell trying to get one OSM file by the end of it.

I currently have everything loaded into a PostGIS database, but I have no idea how to export the whole database to OSM. I also tried just converting to GeoJSON file to OSM, but it used 16GB of RAM and just ran all night at 100% CPU.

All I need to do is, basically, import the microsoft buildings dataset into my OSM file. I don't care if I need to setup a OSM server locally, or whatever needs to happen. I just need a OSM API URL with both datasets, or an OSM XML flat file to load in. I've been at this for two days.

Comment: Which datasets *exactly*? What *exactly* did you try so far and how?

Comment: I think `osmosis` can do this

Comment: Ian is correct.  Osmosis can definitely do the export once you've combined the data in postgres